# JSON Data Parsing in JQuery Starting with an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

Before you mark this question as a duplicate please read it :)
The problem I am having is the JSON file that I am using starts with an array so when I try to parse it I get this:

```
Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Here is the json file that I am trying to parse:

http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2014-1&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592

and this is the code I am using:

```
    var link = "http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date=2014-1&lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592";

    $.getJSON(link, function (json) {
    // Set the variables from the results array
    var cat = json.data[0].catageroy;
        $("#location").replaceWith('Category : ', cat);
});
```

HELP!!!

Thanks

Comment: `var cat = json[0].catageroy;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the .data
just use

```
var cat = json[0];
console.log(cat);
console.log(cat.category);
$("#location").replaceWith('Category : ', cat.category);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the `data` attribute of the json object, which doesn't exist. what you're thinking of as `data` is acutally in `json`, so `json[0].catageroy` will work.